# Layering UIImageView and UIBezierPath

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibezierpath

I have a an array of `UIBezierPath`s which I drew and also a `UIImageView` all put on a `UIView`.  When I draw a `UIBezierPath` and save it to the array, then add a `UIImageView`, then draw another path, the second path will appear behind the image.  Is there something such as a `bringSubViewToFront:` sort of thing for `UIBezierPath`?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    for(int a=0; a<_pathArray.count; a++) {
        [(UIColor )[_colorArray objectAtIndex:a] setStroke];
        [(UIBezierPath)[_pathArray objectAtIndex:a] strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    }
}
```

where `_colorArray` is the array of the colors for each of the paths, and `_pathArray` is the array of the `UIBezierPath`s. I'm inserting a `UIImageView` onto the view and then what I want to do is to be able to draw on the whole `UIView` (including on top of the `UIImageView`).

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: How are you drawing your `UIBezierPath`?  A `UIBezierPath` is not a view.  Are you drawing your paths in a `drawRect:` method, or some other way?  Show us the code that draws your paths.

Comment: I have a drawRect
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    for(int a=0; a<_pathArray.count; a++){
        [(UIColor *)[_colorArray objectAtIndex:a] setStroke];
        [(UIBezierPath*)[_pathArray objectAtIndex:a] strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    }
}
where _colorArray is the array of the colors for each of the paths, and _pathArray is the array of the UIBezierPaths.
I'm inserting a UIImageView onto the view and then what I want to do is to be able to draw on the whole UIView (including on top of the UIImageView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All subviews will always be drawn on "top" of the superview. Bezier paths aren't subviews, they are drawn as part of the view so they will always be behind the subviews.

You can either render the images that you are currently adding to the image views into the current context (during `drawRect`). Or you could add the image views behind the view that you draw the Bezier paths into (by adding them to the same superview, or by adding a new sibling view that the beziers are drawn into.

Comment: What I ended up doing was creating a subclass of UIView on which I draw the UIBezierPaths.  This allowed me to choose whether the UIImageView or the BezierPath was on top. Thanks!